# JS variable not updating when button is clicked in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, drawing

I am making a Drawing/Canvas App on a webpage. I wanted to change the colours via buttons but the variables are not updating the colour. I debugged the code and noticed that it does update but the colour itself has not changed when drawing on the canvas.

HTML:

```
<div id="sketch">
  <canvas id="paint"></canvas>
</div>

<button onClick="changecolour('blue')">Blue</button>
<button onClick="test()">DEBUG</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('#paint');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
var sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));

var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
}, false);

var colour = "black";
function changecolour(choice){
    colour = choice;    
}

function test(click){
    alert("You choose " + colour);
}

ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.strokeStyle = colour;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
}, false);

var onPaint = function() {
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
};
```

Comment: Did you try to add the last piece of code to a funtion? So from ctx.lineWidth till var onPaint .... };??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the variable `strokeStyle` again.

```
function changecolour(choice){
    colour = choice;
    ctx.strokeStyle = colour;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should affect the ctx.strokeStyle itself.  When you first set his value, colour = 'black', which means you set it to black.  It then stays black even tho you change the "colour" value.  So in that case, you just have to do this:

```
function changecolour(choice){
    ctx.strokeStyle = choice;
}
```

Hope that helps